# Kitkat not picking up android:background from Layout XML file, Jelly is OK

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-background

The same XML looks different in Android 4.3 vs 4.4. Problem is that Kitkat (4.4) is not picking up this line: `"android:background="@drawable/darkgray"` (darkgray.jpg is an img)

Why Kitkat is behaving differently?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mavdev.focusoutfacebook"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/darkgray"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_secs2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The difference is as below:

[image]

Comment: Any DPI issue? Where have you put darkgray?

Comment: Thank you - your hint worked. I had darkgray in drawable folder only. I added it to all the folders: drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, and drawable-xxhdpi - and it worked! It was probably because the two phones I was trying it on are of different screen resolution? If you can post this as answer - i will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might because your 4.4 phone has different DPIs. Please double confirm it.